# Virtual packages like 'lua' can't be removed - Raspberry Pi

Tags: lua, raspberry-pi, debian

Overtime I’ve managed to install various versions of Lua, but not being the best at all thing Debian/pi, and after using Lua rocks to install the Lua file system (lfs) module I’ve got more versions (somewhere in my system) that I can shake a stick at.

What can I do to completely remove Lua and start again, this time ensuring is have the lfs module ?

Currently everything I do to try and uninstall/ remove comes to a dead end - usually with the virtual package message..

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lua -v
Lua 5.2.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2013 Lua.org, PUC-Ri0

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-cache depends lua
<lua>

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get purge lua
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Virtual packages like 'lua' can't be removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get remove lua
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Virtual packages like 'lua' can't be removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ luarocks --version
/usr/bin/luarocks 2.2.0
LuaRocks main command-line interface
```

Comment: How'd you install all those Luas?

Answer (score 0):

Many of your apt packages are going to run into complications of system components relying on those being there.  They hardly take up any space anyway, just a couple meg.  Ones you can safely remove will be listed under:

```
apt list lua-* | grep installed
```

---

If you've installed supplemental versions with luaver, then it's

```
luaver list
```

==>  Installed versions: (currently 5.3.5)
5.1.5
5.3.5
5.4.0
5.2.4

```
luaver uninstall 5.4.0
```

so on and so forth, until all the unnecessary vers are off your system.  Alternatively, you could delete your entire `~/.luaver/` directory, and all of those extra versions would be gone in one go.  Then you'd have to reinstall luaver and continue from that point.

Comment: Thanks - running apt list command, all it returned was just one item..   lua-socket/oldoldstable,now 3.0~rc1-3 armhf [installed] yet if I run lua -v it tells me I have 
Lua 5.3.4 ? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and aptitude solved this problem for me:

`apt install aptitude`

here first simulate situation using `-s` for automatically removing/purging your package and its dependencies:
`aptitude -s remove '~i~P<virtual-package>'`
or
`aptitude -s purge '~i~P<virtual-package>'`

Note that sometimes you should choose 'NO' to confirm situation and continue the job for remove/install. When it completed with the fine results you can do the same steps without `-s` parameter to apply these changes on your OS.